# What is Kappa coefficient in HSI classification?

Tags: python, raster, classification, data-quality

What is the Kappa coefficient and how it is calculated in the HSI classification process?

Comment: I know what HSI and kappa are, but I don't understand how you could have a kappa coefficient linked with HSI transform. Could you please be more  specific about the tool (or plugin ) that you are using in QGIS ?

Comment: Sorry Qgis is just a tag, I couldn't use any other tags to [post my question, however the data i am using are "Indian pines.mat , Salinas.mat, Paviauniv.mat", I am using it in python for classification purpose based on deep learning approaches, I found these coefficient calculated in some papers to evaluate their proposed methods

Comment: please edit your question with your details nad remove the part about hsi but mention the deep learning. the names of your files is not necessary, but the number of classes could be.

Comment: note that the use of kappa has been heavily criticized by Pontius https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01431161.2011.552923